# Change to the next image when clickon button using jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, buttonclick

**I want to change to the next image when clicking on button using jquery, displaying one image at a time, should I use hide/show, display: none or .remove/.append? **

```js
$("#next").toggle(function(){
  function(){
    $('#planet1').remove();
    $('#planet2').append();
  });
  function(){
    $(this).remove('#planet2').append('#planet3');
  });
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass('planet3').addClass('planet4');
  });
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass('planet4').addClass('planet5');
  });
});
```

```html
          <div class="planets">
              <img id="planet1" src="img\planets\planet1.png" />
              <img id="planet2" src="img\planets\planet2.png" />
              <img id="planet3" src="img\planets\planet3.png" />
              <img id="planet4" src="img\planets\planet4.png" />
              <img id="planet5" src="img\planets\planet5.png" />
          </div>
              <button id="next"> Make a greener planet</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain your though process being creating all those anonymous functions which, btw, have syntax errors with the ); at the end of them?  Also `remove()`, according to the api, doesn't take a selector, but an element as it's first input, and `append('string')` will just append that string.  Also why are you using the `toggle` method on a button for this rather than a click handler?

Comment: There are no end of tutorials on the web for doing this and lots and lots of scripts also. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to accomplish what you are looking for with some basic jQuery and CSS. First, you will set all images to be hidden by default, with only the first shown.

```
img:first-of-type {
  display: inherit;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

Then you can have a function that rotates through.

```
$('#next').click(function() {
  currentPicture++;
  if (currentPicture > $('img').length) {
    currentPicture = 1;
  }
  $('img').css('display', 'none');
  $(`#planet${currentPicture}`).css('display', 'inherit');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmnhdknL/1/

Comment: **thanks!** @jmaz this is what I was looking for thanks thanks

Comment: it was more elaborate than I thought haha I´ll go through your thought process on the solution @jmaz